# Realm Self hosted or Realm Cloud

Tags: realm, realm-mobile-platform

I’m developing an app for botanists where they can take picture of plants (most of time it will be offline) then it should be sync to the server. I might have some 7.500 users/month and each user must have available about 20 GB. What is the best choice, use self hosted or realm cloud?

Comment: I'd suggest u to use amazon services

Comment: You probably shouldn't want to create Realm files that are 20 GB in size.

Comment: @LabLab so how can I integrate realm to amazon services?

Comment: I'd store the images outside of Realm, just store a uri to the image location.  You could easily use Realm Cloud and an AWS S3 bucket to store the images.